# How to access individual values using Xpath?

Tags: xpath

The following xpath that I have returns 3 table items and I would like to access each value individually.

`//div[@class='transform section']//div[@class='inner-border-section-gray-container']//div[@class='related-tables-section']//div[@class='inner-section']//span[@class='related-tables']`

[image]

How can I access "customer", "lineitem" and "orders" individually using xpath?

Can someone please help with the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `/text()` to get text nodes that is direct child of the `<span>` :

```
//span[@class='related-tables']/text()
```

you may want to add condition to filter out empty text nodes :

```
//span[@class='related-tables']/text()[normalize-space()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to supply them individually with a surrounding element? Then you could use the data attribute, if using Razer syntax you must say data_myVariable="something" otherwise replace the "_" with a "-" and you can then access the data attribute using data-myVariable.